# How is the implicit function theorem used here.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

I am reading a paper in which it says the following:

> Here, $\Gamma$ is an analytic a curve in $\mathbb{C}^n$ defined near the origin. Write $z = x +iy$ and suppose that for each pair $(t_x, t_y) \in T_0(\Gamma)$ were have $|t_x|^2 \geq |t_y|^2$ (here, $T_0$ denotes the Tangent space). The author claims that by the implicit function theorem there exists a neighbourhood of the origin where $\Gamma$ is given by
>   $$
> \{x+itH(x) : x\in W\}
> $$
>   where $W\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $H$ is real analytic.

I am not sure how this follows from the implicit function theorem. I'd appreciate it if anyone could clarify what is going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does this question have to do with the steepest descent method?

Comment: @Rahul Theorem 2.8. is a general asymptotic approximation which uses a method similar to the method of steepest descent. In the PDF it's called the saddle point method but I was told that in this case it was also called the method of steepest descent

Comment: OK, if you say so. But my feeling is that the current title makes it sound like a question about numerical methods rather than about complex analysis, so it may not get enough attention from complex analysis experts (which I think is what you need to get a good answer). And is the question really supposed to be tagged real-analysis?

Comment: Alright! I'll change the title/tags. Thanks for the advice :-)

Comment: Could you indicate how this "analytic curve" $\Gamma$ is given, and what the tacit regularity assumptions are?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I linked the paper I was reading. It's on page 13, in the proof of theorem 2.8. http://webpages.csus.edu/mjv/SjostrandSAM.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $z=x+iy \mapsto x$ is a submersion, and its differential has kernel $\{iy|y \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$. So the map is a local diffeomorphism on $\Gamma$ near $0$, as the kernel of the differential is zero, so the differential is an isomorphism of real vector spaces. It follows that there is a local inverse $x \mapsto (x,y(x))$.

Comment: I haven't taken much differential geometry, so please confirm id I understood correctly: The kernel of the differential is contained in $\{iy : y\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$. But since $|t_x| \geq |t_y|$ the kernel can only contain zero. The differential is therefore an isomorphism and we can apply the implicit function theorem

Comment: Yes, that is correct.